# What is the easiest way to do multi party video conferencing

Tags: software-recommendation, remote-desktop

Whats the best way to:

- create a video conference that can handle at least 4 people.
- stream your desktop to be viewed by multiple people in the conference.

Answer (score 1):

Faceflow offers a four way video conferencing.
http://www.faceflow.com/video-conference

Answer (score 0):

[Google+ Hangouts](http://www.google.com/tools/dlpage/res/talkvideo/hangouts/) supports this.